# jsp - whats wrong with my import of a jar file?

Tags: java, jsp, jar, e-commerce, mastercard

I am trying to integrate Simplify Commerce payment system into my project
but I can't seem to get it right.

This is one of the problems:

```
<%@ page import="com.simplify.package"%>
and I got this error after mousing over the red wavy line:  

Syntax error on token "package", * expected
 I then added a `*` like this `com.simplify.package.*`  

 And I got this: 
 `Syntax error on token "package", Identifier expected`

 I already added all the .jar files to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
  What seems to be the problem?
```

The jsp that I am trying to import the jar file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.simplify.package.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Pay Now!</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    PaymentsApi.PUBLIC_KEY =  "";
    PaymentsApi.PRIVATE_KEY = "";

    CardToken cardToken = CardToken.create(new PaymentsMap()
        .set("card.addressCity", "OFallon")
        .set("card.addressState", "MO")
        .set("card.cvc", "123")
        .set("card.expMonth", 11)
        .set("card.expYear", 19)
        .set("card.number", "5105105105105100")
);

System.out.println(cardToken);
%>
```

There are red way lines under `PaymentsApi` and `CardToken`

Comment: Before this line in there in your jsp, can you show that code here

Comment: this is the code before that line `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>` and this is the very first line. @Ashish Singh

Comment: Did you check if a package with structure 'com.simplify.package' exists ?

Comment: how do i check for that? @Ashish Singh

Comment: By going through the documentation provided for the jar-file. Maybe open the file in win-rar and see the package structure exists. It's most likely that there is no such package structure

Comment: Oh I've found it! Thank you very much @Ashish Singh!

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking the jar file to look at the package structure solved it.